# Solr commands not returning json output

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, solr

I was going through the php documentation for solr and wanted to try out the basic example. But the expected output isn't received and a blank page is returned when i try the following code with my existing project.

```
<?php
include "bootstrap.php";

$options = array
(
'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
'login'    => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
'port'     => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);

$doc = new SolrInputDocument();



$doc->addField('ID', 334455);
//$doc->addField('cat', 'Software');
//$doc->addField('cat', 'Lucene');

$updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);

print_r($updateResponse->getResponse());

?>
```

The bootstrap.php goes something like this:

```
/* Domain name of the Solr server */
define('SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');

/* Whether or not to run in secure mode */
define('SOLR_SECURE', false);

/* HTTP Port to connection */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8443 : 8080));

/* HTTP Basic Authentication Username */
define('SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME', 'admin');

/* HTTP Basic Authentication password */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'changeit');

/* HTTP connection timeout */
/* This is maximum time in seconds allowed for the http data transfer operation.Default value is 30 seconds */
define('SOLR_SERVER_TIMEOUT', 10);

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private key + private certificate (concatenated in that    order) */
define('SOLR_SSL_CERT', 'certs/combo.pem');

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private certificate only */
define('SOLR_SSL_CERT_ONLY', 'certs/solr.crt');

/* File name to a PEM-formatted private key */
define('SOLR_SSL_KEY', 'certs/solr.key');

/* Password for PEM-formatted private key file */
define('SOLR_SSL_KEYPASSWORD', 'StrongAndSecurePassword');

/* Name of file holding one or more CA certificates to verify peer with*/
define('SOLR_SSL_CAINFO', 'certs/cacert.crt');

/* Name of directory holding multiple CA certificates to verify peer with */
define('SOLR_SSL_CAPATH', 'certs/');

?>
```

I'm using the tomcat username and password for solr_server_username/password. and solr is working fine otherwise on the UI. I am using solr 4.6.1 with php solrclient 1.0.2

```
    <?php

// make sure browsers see this page as utf-8 encoded HTML
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$limit = 10;
$query = isset($_REQUEST['q']) ? $_REQUEST['q'] : false;
$results = false;

if ($query)
{
  // The Apache Solr Client library should be on the include path
  // which is usually most easily accomplished by placing in the
  // same directory as this script ( . or current directory is a default
  // php include path entry in the php.ini)
  require_once('/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php');

  // create a new solr service instance - host, port, and webapp
  // path (all defaults in this example)
  $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', 8080, '/solr/collection1');


  // if magic quotes is enabled then stripslashes will be needed
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1)
  {
    $query = stripslashes($query);
  }

  // in production code you'll always want to use a try /catch for any
  // possible exceptions emitted  by searching (i.e. connection
  // problems or a query parsing error)
  try
  {
    $results = $solr->search($query, 0, $limit);
  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
    // in production you'd probably log or email this error to an admin
        // and then show a special message to the user but for this example
        // we're going to show the full exception

        die("<html><head><title>SEARCH EXCEPTION</title><body><pre>{$e->__toString()}</pre></body></html>");
  }
}

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Solr Client Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>ABCD</h1>
    <form  accept-charset="utf-8" method="get">
      <label for="q">Search:</label>
      <input id="q" name="q" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($query, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php

// display results
if ($results)
{
  $total = (int) $results->response->numFound;
  $start = min(1, $total);
  $end = min($limit, $total);
?>
    <div>Results <?php echo $start; ?> - <?php echo $end;?> of <?php echo $total; ?>:</div>
    <ol>
<?php
  // iterate result documents
  foreach ($results->response->docs as $doc)
  {
?>
      <li>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: left">
<?php
    // iterate document fields / values
    foreach ($doc as $field => $value)
    {
?>
          <tr>
            <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($field, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?></td>
          </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
        </table>
      </li>
    <?php
  }
?>
    </ol>
    <?php
    }?>
```

While trying the above alternative code, the following error is encountered:

> exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''0'
>   Status: Communication Error' in
>   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php:338
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php(1170):
>
> Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet - `('http://localhos...')`
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/testproject/tryout.php(33): Apache_Solr_Service->search('abhilash', 0, 10)
>
> ## 2 {main}

Comment: u may want to define the constants before u use them in code ($options).

Comment: I have defined that in the bootstrap.php which i've shown right below the first segment of the code. Oops, my bad! I'll edit that now.

Comment: So u say that the commented lines of the third code-sniplet work?

Comment: I'm sorry again, these lines arent really commented in the program. It was a mistake while pasting here.But yes, that segment is what is throwing the error. I'm really sorry for an ill formatted question. I've made the changes now.

Comment: This may helps you out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php-solr-client/GoMBww0jl5Y if not try to comment all lines and debug the variables starting from the top - if working go to the next line - else post error here

Comment: Thanks for the link @F.Müller I have been reading that thread and have been trying to clear this problem on the thread's basis for couple of hours now. The resolution however isn't common to any of the solutions mentioned there at least on my system. My issue is much analogous to tha of [kfmnla's](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/php-solr-client/GoMBww0jl5Y/vFc4K5iMZpEJ) but the inclusion of text field isn't the issue in my case.

Comment: Also while trying to run: php -r "echo Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', 8080, '/solr/collection1/');" the error thrown is :"PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Apache_Solr_Service() in Command line code on line 1" but phpsolrclient extension is already enabled!

Comment: because u call it as a function - try print_r(new Apache_Solr...) instead or even var_dump(...)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. But I still cant figure out any errors there.

Answer (score 1):

Solr's default response writer is XML.

If you want to get back your results in JSON, you should specify it by defining the URL parameter wt=json

Example

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/customers/select?q=customerSearchName&wt=json
```

Make sure that you do so.

Comment: Okay, but where can i do that when I'm using $solr->search($query, 0, $limit);

Comment: I am not familiar with the PHP Api to Solr. As far as I understand the following page might be helpful to you

http://www.php.net/manual/en/solrclient.setresponsewriter.php

You should do something like 

$solr->setResponseWriter(``type of response here'')

where the type of response can be XML or "phpnative". It seems that JSON is not supported.

If you want to have JSON as return type, you can do this by using the curl method in PHP and get back your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
'wt' => 'json'
```

to the array you pass into SolrClient()

See http://php.net/manual/en/solrclient.construct.php